# Revisiting a paper?

Tags: publications, data

I am researching the field of micro (and some macro) economics. I wrote an article that is forthcoming. One key limitation I had, was some missing data. Now, some quite time later, I was able to get my hands on this data. I am thinking about "revisiting" my former work. That is, I am wondering if I can build on my old work, cite it specifically, raise attention to the major limitation, and remedy it in a new paper. I have two questions:

(1) When is a revisit normally undertaken? Can I do this as planned?

(2) What format does a revisit have? That is, does it need to have all theory again etc etc?

Comment: What field are you in? In some fields such as CS, it is a normal option that a peer-reviewed conference publication may be built upon in a longer journal publication that has no really novel contribution of its own, just, for example, an extended description of results or data.

Comment: What do you mean by "revisit"?  Publish another paper? I think you should say this specifically.

Comment: OK, I will edit the questions and add some more details.

Comment: I now added some more detail

Comment: Maybe the word you are looking for may is *follow-up paper*.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I tried to research if there are any related topics on "follow-ups". I failed to find any. Do you have any recomendations on the topic?

Comment: I think you can give a much briefer account of the background material the second time around.  Refer people back to the first paper for more detail.  Make sure the first paper is easily available online.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is almost certainly ok.  This is how most research works.  You write a paper given the data you have.  A while later you are able to get your hands on more data.  This data provides extra insights in your paper.

The format should focus on the new data.  Usually these paper have a line in the intro to the effect of "we build on work done in paper X" and then goes on to explain that you have new data and how you got it.

Focus on the difference between conclusions you drew in your original paper, and what information this new data provides (i.e. we were unsure the importance of Y, but we can now see its effect).

Comment: Thank you! Is there any kind of formal advise on how to write follow-up paper? In my case, theory and sample remain the same. I would just like to extend my work with a new variable that I couldn't get my hands when I wrote the initial paper...

Comment: Focus on the new variable.  That is exactly what a follow up paper is for.